# package makeidx: print first letter for each group of keys

Tags: indexing

I've created index with `makeidx` package. It works. What really need is to print the first letter above every group of keys (i.e. referring to the image I want to print the red letter, that I have manually inserted).

[image]

Answer (score 16):

According to [How to create capital letter for index](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=51&t=8096) you would require the following in a file `test.ist` (or `test.mst`<sup>*</sup>):

```
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "\\textsf\{\\color\{red\}"
heading_suffix "\}\\nopagebreak\n"
```

Then when you run `makeindex`, you need to use the `-s` option to specify this style file (assuming your document is called `test.tex`):

```
makeindex -s test.ist test.idx
```

The first flag set allows for the creation of the header (a letter). The second `prefix` and third `suffix` flag wraps the header contents to obtain the appropriate formatting (`{\textsf{\color{red}...}` in this case).

<sup>*</sup> According to [`makeindex` man page](http://cims.nyu.edu/cgi-systems/man.cgi?section=1&topic=makeindex), "If exactly one input file was given and no explicit style file was specified using `-s`, `makeindex` uses a file with the extension `.mst` as default style file (when present)."

Comment: or save as `mst` file.

Comment: I suggest to change the last `.ist` line to `heading_suffix "}\\nopagebreak\n"`.

Comment: @lockstep: Good suggestion - didn't think about page breaking!

Comment: I'm  using TexMaker to compile file, I can't manual compile.

Comment: @Mariano: That's the reason why you should use `mst`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel How could I use mst file?

Comment: @Mariano: According to [`makeindex` man page](http://cims.nyu.edu/cgi-systems/man.cgi?section=1&topic=makeindex), "If exactly one input file was given and no explicit style file was specified using `-s`, `makeindex` uses a file with the extension `.mst` as default style file (when present)."