# Index with an initial letter of the group

Tags: formatting, indexing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [package makeidx: print first letter for each group of keys](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53986/package-makeidx-print-first-letter-for-each-group-of-keys)

I'm trying to adapt the index of my contribution such that each group of words (starting with the same letter) has the starting letter displayed as bold an on top of the group.

Note that I tried to find an answer, but the related questions and answers are rather confusing. I use `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}` and `\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex`.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17213/layouting-the-index-page

Answer (score 19, accepted):

We need to create an `.ist`style file and tell `makeindex` to use it. My style file is as follows:

```
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "{\\textbf{"
heading_suffix "}}\\nopagebreak\n"
```

The first line tells `makeindex` to display a heading for each group (`1` stands for `true`). The last two lines will format the heading the way you want (I used `textbf` to make the heading bold).

Now, with `myheader.ist`, we simply call

```
makeindex -s myheader.ist myfile.idx
```

Consider this example:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeindex: { style: myheader.ist }
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

Some text.\index{Apple}\index{Apricot}\index{Avocado}\index{Banana}
\index{Bilberry}\index{Blackberry}\index{Blackcurrant}\index{Blueberry}
\index{Currant}\index{Cherry}\index{Cherimoya}\index{Clementine}
\index{Date}\index{Damson}\index{Dragonfruit}\index{Durian}
\index{Eggplant}\index{Elderberry}\index{Feijoa}\index{Gooseberry}
\index{Grape}\index{Grapefruit}\index{Guava}\index{Huckleberry}
\index{Jackfruit}\index{Jambul}\index{Kiwi fruit}\index{Kumquat}
\index{Legume}\index{Lemon}\index{Lime}\index{Lychee}\index{Mandarine}
\index{Mango}\index{Melon}\index{Nectarine}\index{Orange}\index{Peach}
\index{Pear}\index{Pitaya}\index{Physalis}\index{Plum}\index{Pineapple}
\index{Pomegranate}\index{Purple Mangosteen}\index{Raisin}\index{Raspberry}
\index{Rambutan}\index{Redcurrant}\index{Salal berry}\index{Satsuma}
\index{Star fruit}\index{Strawberry}\index{Tangerine}\index{Tomato}
\index{Ugli fruit}\index{Watermelon}\index{Ziziphus mauritiana}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Running the following commands:

```
pdflatex myfile.tex
makeindex -s myheader.ist myfile.idx
pdflatex myfile.tex
```

We will obtain this output:

[image: My index]

Hope it helps. `:)`

Comment: I thought that if you use the `makeidx` package, it runs makeindex internally for you, so you don't need a separate run. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @Brent.Longborough: The package `imakeidx` has this functionality.

Comment: @Brent: `makeidx` provides a couple of extra commands to the default indexing mechanism, but that's all. As Marco mentioned, `imakeidx` has this feature. `:)`

Comment: This works also with sections, i.e. `heading_prefix "{\\section*{"`, in order to have consistent formatting with bibliographies grouped by initial letters, like here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150068/how-to-split-the-bibliography-alphabetically

Comment: I'm using overleaf online, How can I adapt it to the remote version ?