# Printing index in 2 columns with starting letter before every section

Tags: indexing, imakeidx

I'm trying to make an index looking like this -- 2 columns, starting letter at the beginning of each section:

[image]

I tried to use

```
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
 .
 .
 .
\printindex
```

the result looked good since it contained starting letter, but was printed only in one column:

[image]

so I tried using this:

```
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[columns = 2]
.
.
.
\printindex
```

and the index was divided into 2 columns, but starting letters disappeared

Can someone please help me how to make it the way I need?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your question is close related to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65247/index-with-an-initial-letter-of-the-group.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add the starting lines exactly like in the following example:

```
%%%% A simple MakeIndex style
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.mst}
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "{\\textbf{"
heading_suffix "}}\\nopagebreak\n"
\end{filecontents*}
%%% end

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex % two column is the default

\begin{document}

Some text

\index{Apple}\index{Apricot}

\index{Banana}\index{Cherry}

\index{Lemon}\index{Lime}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing, works like charm! Exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot buddy.

Comment: IS it fonctional with the remote version of overleaf ?