# Group Unicode indices header

Tags: unicode, makeindex

I followed this post [Index with an initial letter of the group](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65247/index-with-an-initial-letter-of-the-group)
But anyone show me how to create a Unicode header like in the picture below ("Chỉ mục" (in Vietnamese) mean "Index"), In Vietnamese have some characters like 'Ư', 'Ơ', 'Đ', 'Ă',...So, what i want is create group header for those characters. (In the picture i want the character 'Ư'):
[image]

please help me. Thank you all.