# Use VSCode to generate modified Index

Tags: makeindex

I am attempting to use VSCode to generate an index that is separated by the first letter of the word as shown [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65247/index-with-an-initial-letter-of-the-group) [image]

I created the `.ist` file as suggested:

```
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "{\\textbf{"
heading_suffix "}}\\nopagebreak\n"
```

and placed the `.ist` file into a folder named "Packages".

I am not getting the Index to show up with the modified settings as shown above.  Can you assist me in getting the correct output?

Thanks!

**CODE**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[options=-s ../Packages/myindex.ist, intoc]


\begin{document}

Some text.\index{Apple}\index{Apricot}\index{Avocado}\index{Banana}
\index{Bilberry}\index{Blackberry}\index{Blackcurrant}\index{Blueberry}
\index{Currant}\index{Cherry}\index{Cherimoya}\index{Clementine}
\index{Date}\index{Damson}\index{Dragonfruit}\index{Durian}
\index{Eggplant}\index{Elderberry}\index{Feijoa}\index{Gooseberry}
\index{Grape}\index{Grapefruit}\index{Guava}\index{Huckleberry}
\index{Jackfruit}\index{Jambul}\index{Kiwi fruit}\index{Kumquat}
\index{Legume}\index{Lemon}\index{Lime}\index{Lychee}\index{Mandarine}
\index{Mango}\index{Melon}\index{Nectarine}\index{Orange}\index{Peach}
\index{Pear}\index{Pitaya}\index{Physalis}\index{Plum}\index{Pineapple}
\index{Pomegranate}\index{Purple Mangosteen}\index{Raisin}\index{Raspberry}
\index{Rambutan}\index{Redcurrant}\index{Salal berry}\index{Satsuma}
\index{Star fruit}\index{Strawberry}\index{Tangerine}\index{Tomato}
\index{Ugli fruit}\index{Watermelon}\index{Ziziphus mauritiana}

\newpage
\cleardoublepage
\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: vscode is not relevant here, that's just the editor you use to write the source.

Comment: I used `-s myindex.ist,` and put `myindex,ist` in the same directory as the document and got the output you asked for, https://www.overleaf.com/read/tpjvtpcnwfwc#838713

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thanks for your inputs.  I am using VSCode as the LaTeX compiler.  Good datapoint that the code works on its own.  You are correct then, there might be a VSCode setting that is not causing the Index to show up correctly.

Comment: @DaiBowen, I am not getting the Index to show via using VSCode as the compiler.

Comment: @Joe no vscode is not a compiler it is a text editor, you have an underlying tex system (texlive or miktex) and you would get the same output whatever editor you used to write the source file.

Comment: @Joe if the index does not appear you will have an error from  latex or from makeindex you should show the `.log` or `.llg` log files

Comment: is the packages folder at the correct relative location ../  ie under the parent directory of the directory with your source file

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, yes, the packages folder is under the parent directory.

Comment: The `.idx` file has the entries....I also get the message from the VSCode `log` file...`runsystem(makeindex -s ../Packages/myindex.ist Example_Index.idx)...executed safely (allowed).`  Although this takes place, I do not see the `.llg` file

Comment: sorry typo `.ilg` not `.llg`

Comment: actually I'm surprised it can access a parent directory in restricted shell escape, what hapens if you delete `../Packages` and put the ist next to the document

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried your suggestion but I got the same results. :-(

Comment: check first it works outside the editor, just cd to the directory and `pdflatex yourfile.tex`  and check that works.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, in the `cmd` prompt via `pdflatex myfile.tex`, I get the correct index to show up.

Comment: @Joe so the problem is in your vscode setup not any of the code you have shown

Comment: @Joe, have you seen this solution https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65249/245790 from the Linked "column" to the right?

Comment: @MS-SPO, thanks for your input.  I did see that post and that was where I got the original formatting for this post.  However, I am having an issue of it working with VSCode.  Thanks!