# How to make index with alphabetic order?

Tags: indexing, kile

Consider the following example :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx,multicol}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
All\index{All},Apple\index{Apple}, Ball\index{Ball}, , Small\index{Small},     Zoo\index{Zoo}

 \printindex

\end{document}
```

Produces :
[image]

But I want like this :
[image]

I use kile in ubuntu10.04. How can I do my job ?

Comment: Use Xindy instead of MakeIndex. Xindy will give you an index with blocks for each letter and the letter itself as a kind of header.

Comment: @ Thorsten Donig I have replaced 'MakeIndex' by 'Xindy' but shows an erros : undefined control sequence\Xindy

Comment: I didn't tell you to replace `\makeindex`. You have to setup your editor for use with Xindy. Your code example will (almost) be left untouched. I provided an answer that might help.

Comment: take a look at this: [package makeidx: print first letter for each group of keys](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53986/579)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[makeindex]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[options=-s lou3.ist]
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
All\index{All},Apple\index{Apple}, Ball\index{Ball}, , Small\index{Small},     Zoo\index{Zoo}

 \printindex

\end{document}
```

and "lou3.ist" as a file in the same dir as your main file:

```
quote '+'
headings_flag 1
symhead_positive "Symbole"
numhead_positive "Zahlen"
heading_prefix "{\\bf "
heading_suffix "}\\nopagebreak%\n \\indexspace\\nopagebreak%"
delim_r "~--~"
suffix_2p "\\,f"
suffix_3p "\\,ff"
preamble
"\\markright{INDEX}\n\n\\begin{theindex}\n\\thispagestyle{headings}\n"
postamble "\n\n\\end{theindex}\n"
```

Comment: 1 error occurs with this as follows : `imakeidx.sty' not found.\makeindex

Answer (score 2):

You can use Xindy instead of MakeIndex to get the desired output. But first you have to set up your editor (Kile) for that. Go to menu Options → Configure Kile and in the tree on the left go to Tools → Build and then select MakeIndex. In the upper right corner choose Xindy from the drop down menu (see screen capture).

[image]

Note that my system is German and the names on your system for sure will differ. But this should give you the necessary orientation.

Now you can slightly modify your code example and prepare it for use with Xindy.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}

\makeindex

\begin{document}
  All\index{All}, Apple\index{Apple}, Ball\index{Ball}, Small\index{Small}, Zoo\index{Zoo}

 \printindex
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: According to you I have configured kile with Xindy.After this an error also occurs for your given code. error is : " `imakeidx.sty' not found.^^M ". How can I fix this in my system ubuntu10.04

Comment: @SoumitraSen: Install that package subsequently by [the package manager of your TeX distribution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437). Since you have a rather old Linux system, you probably need to install vanilla TeX Live 2013 and replace the TeX system from the repository of your Linux distribution. If for some reasons you don't manage to install »[imakeidx](http://ctan.org/pkg/imakeidx)«, you can continue using »[makeidx](http://ctan.org/pkg/makeidx)«.