# Indexing in Latex with printing the first letter for each group , on a WINDOWS system?

Tags: indexing, windows

I've created index with makeidx package. It works. I just need to print the first letter above every group of keys. My problem is the same cited here ([package makeidx: print first letter for each group of keys](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53986/package-makeidx-print-first-letter-for-each-group-of-keys)) but the solution given is for a Linux system not Windows. 
I created the .ist file. But the command "makeindex -s test.ist test.idx" is not a solution since i work on a windows system. 
Can anyone help me?

Comment: A warm welcome to TeX.SE! Share with the community what code you have tried. To the best of my knowledge TeX and LaTeX commands usually work the same no matter the operating system.

Comment: I mean for the command "makeindex -s test.ist test.idx" it is written in the "linux" command window . In my case, working with "Windows", where can i execute this command? It should exist an alternative to that command that tells the makeidx to use the .ist file.

Comment: Take a look at _What makes a good MWE_ http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3343/what-makes-a-good-mwe In my experience, questions that have a MWE generate faster, better, and more useful answers.

Comment: I haven't had Windows in years, but from the internet: Click Start: In the Search or Run line type cmd and press enter. That should get you to the command line where you can run your commands.  Make sure you are in the directory with your TeX files or it will not work. Don't be shocked if this question is eventually closed as off topic, it happens sometimes with questions that are more about an underlying operating system.  Best of luck with your TeXing!