# How to generate a keyword index at end of a document?

Tags: indexing

I'm writing a report and I want to make a list of index as given in the below picture.

[image]

How I achieve this?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Indexing

Comment: Do you speak (read) german? If yes, you may like to take a look at my blog: http://tobiw.de/tbdm/index-1 and http://tobiw.de/tbdm/index-2

Comment: If you use `xindy` instead of `mekeindex` can do more flexible your index due a its powerful capabilities.

Comment: @skpblack If it runs. xindy tends to crash sometimes and on Windows you need luck to get it to work.

Comment: @TeXnician, Luck isn't necessary, `xindy` comes with the last version of _[Miktex](https://miktex.org/download)_ for _Windows_, *only* is necessary to download and install a `perl` interpreter such as _[ActiveState Perl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads)_ or _[Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/)_. I have always been a Windows user.

Comment: @skpblack And obviously a MikTeX user. There are other distributions out there. But that's not a discussion which should appear under a question.

Answer (score 2):

Usually it will suffice to use the package `makeidx` or the more modern `imakeidx`. Then put `\makeindex` into your preamble. And in your document you can use `\printindex` to show it.

After compiling your document with f.i. `pdflatex` make sure to also compile with `makeindex` and then with `pdflatex` again.

If you want those groups of letters have a look at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53986/124577) post. It explains how to do it.

Just a basic example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
This is a test\index{test}
\clearpage\printindex
\end{document}
```